# Coldfusion - populate pdf using cfpdfform

Tags: xml, pdf, coldfusion

How can we populate a pdf using cfpdfform and xml data. Here is my requirement

1. We have pdf template file
2. Currently we use java library and specify x-axis and y-axis coordinates to populate the pdf.
3. use query to populate the pdf

Since the pdf template is not stationary and get updated with new fields every now and then, we are planning to use something more straight forward instead of using x and y-coordinates which gets really painful to adjust until we get it right

I started looking at cfpdfform. When I read the template file using cfpdfform, I see that it was designed using LiveCycle. I also tried reading a file using below code

```
<cfpdfform action="read" file="file.pdf" xmldata="x" />
<cfdump var="#x#">
```

Then I created an xml file using the output "x" created above.

```
<cffile action="write" file="C:/myfolder/file.xml"  output="#x#">
```

Then using the above xml file or xml variable 'x', I tried to populate the file.xml

```
<cfpdfform action="populate" source="file.pdf"
   destination="file_updated.pdf" xmldata="file.xml" />
```

At this point I get an error that "**Either datafile XML or data XML contained in the PDF document is invalid."**

Is this the right way to do it.

Also some of my questions are as below

1. cfpdfform does not show all the field names on pdf especially on headers etc
2. Is this the best way to approach this problem or do you suggest any other alternatives.

Thanks

Comment: Is the real code using absolute file paths?

Comment: all the files are in same folder. Its relative paths

Comment: I tend to distrust relative paths because sometimes they're not relative to the same thing. Just for grins, any difference using absolute paths for all?

Comment: @Ageax Thanks for the suggestion, it seems to be working now

Comment: @DB3 - Glad it helped.  Regarding 2) have you tried out `cfpdfformfield`? It's a more granular method of populating form fields (i.e. individually by name vs bulk load by xml). Might test it out as well to get a feel for the pros and cons of each.

Comment: cdpdfformfield did not seem to work. Also any idea of other generic libraries that we can use for this pdf population using xml schema that can be also used across other programming languages

Comment: It should work with those forms, once you get the structure down.  I don't know of any offhand. With LC forms you're more closely wedded to Adobe. There might be a few java libs out there, but likely nothing as simple as using cfpdfform.